# Serialize NHibernate POCO to XML

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, serialization

I want to serialize my NHibernate POCO classes to XML to use in an XSLT transformation. I've tried using DataContractSerializer but it fails as it does not recognize the proxied objects and the one-to-many mappings contained in ISet members. Should I use DataContractSerializer or is there another way to achieve this? Secondly, is there a generic DataContractResolver which will work with proxied objects, custom classes and sets? Bear in mind that I only want to serialize and not deserialize.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that you'd be better off not serializing your nHibernate POCOs at all.
Personally, I'd create some DTOs and then serialize those.
The reason for that is that I want to have *full control* over what I'm serializing.
If I serialize an nHib POCO, I don't know whether my collection properties are populated or not, and if not- I'm not sure what nHib has put there without me knowing.

Converting to a DTO would give me the advantage of explicitly deciding what to load (and serialize) and what not to.

BTW- If you're serializing your object in order to send them over a service or some such, Ayende has [some harsh (and true) words](http://ayende.com/blog/4011/the-stripper-pattern) for you :)

Comment: Yes, very good advice, but in this case I'm transforming XML to PDF using XSL-FO on the local server. Presently, I was using DataTables and DataSets using a native connection but since I'm using NHibernate I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: @AndrewWheeler oh I see. so Ayende's comments don't apply in your case. However, I believe that the idea of serializing DTOs and not your POCOs still holds, though.